# How to attach MatPaginator to datasource coming from server in angular material table?

Tags: angular, typescript, gridview, pagination, angular-material

I am using [angular Material table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) to create grid in my Angular 5 project. 
My data is coming from http request and its assigned to a variable  called dataSourceNew like this in view.ts file. Here dataSourceNew has dynamic content and strucuture and so I am not exporting any interface.

```
      this.http.get('http://example.org?,{headers: this.headers})
          .subscribe(
          res => { 

           this.displayedColumnsNew = res.record;
           this.dataSourceNew = res.data;
           this.matdatasource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataSourceNew);
           this.dataSourceNew.paginator = this.paginator;
           console.log("got matdatasource object",this.matdatasource);
      // attached the result of this log below

         });
```

I am successfully able to create a data-table using this syntax in html file.

```
     <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
           <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSourceNew">


       <ng-container  *ngFor="let head of tableData.record; let i= index; " matColumnDef="{{head}}" (click)="setClickedRow(ddata) "  [class.active]="ddata[primaryid] == selectedRow">
               <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{tableData.gridhead[i]}} 
                </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[head]}} </mat-cell>
         </ng-container>


     <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsNew"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsNew;">
        </mat-row>
            </mat-table>
     </div>
```

Now I want to attach a pagination to this table and for that I have declared this

```
 @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

But When I attach the pagination to table in html like this,

```
  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                 [showFirstLastButtons]="true">
  </mat-paginator>
```

I got the below error in console and it breaks my application.

I have already imported this

```
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
```

In respective .ts file.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'pageSize' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-paginator'.
1. If 'mat-paginator' is an Angular component and it has 'pageSize' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-paginator' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
```

Also when I log this.dataSourcenew: 
The paginator element of this object is empty : 
How can I use the angular material paginator without creating any interface?

Update :

With David's suggestion : 
I have added MatPaginator to the main app module's imports. Now the pagination block is showing perfectly.

But the Current Records shows as "0 of 0". even though I have 14 records, and Pagination functions like changing number of records,next, previous etc are not working. What I am missing?

Update 2: I have applied the property Length to paginator tags.Now The pagination is working fine. The issue is that now the datatable is not changing the current no. of rows.

Update 3: As per the suggestion from Pierre Mallet I have done the needed changes. and now without explicitly telling the [length] total record is getting inferred from the api response. Also the paginator is correctly binded with my     `this.matdatasource = new MatTableDataSource([]);` So no explicit codding is done till now to achieve this.

Now I just want to fetch few records initially (lets say 20) and then want to do database call from subsequent requests, so that I don't need to hit the db at once for all the records. How to achieve this?

Comment: You need to add MatPaginator to the module's imports as well

Comment: @David I have added MatPaginator to the main app module's imports. Now the pagination block is showing perfectly. But the Current Records shows as "0 of 0". even though I have 14 records, and Pagination functions like changing number of records,next, previous etc are not working.

Comment: You need to specify the [length] property of the paginator. https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview. Here is a complete tutorial https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/

Comment: @David Thanks . Now it showing the total record and next,previous button are working fine but the table output is not getting updated? Any custom functions to write?

Comment: Did you have a look at the tutorial link ?

Comment: Yes That tutorial is the exact thing I was looking for. I am getting the pagination variables on server side and now will change the Datasourcenew variable accordingly.

Comment: @David, is it possible to achieve this without involving Observable-based API from pagination? Because I have already one function calling db and fetching records.

Comment: Have a look at PageEvent event

Answer (score 8):

You have to wait for your paginator to be instantiated before "linking" it to your MatTableDataSource, so usually, you would listen to AfterViewInit hooks to get the paginator through `@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;`

But as your data is asynchronous as well you should

1. init an empty DataSource
2. populate the dataSource when your data is ready
3. link the paginator after the view has been rendered

Could you try this ?

```
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  private this.matdatasource;

  // get refereence to paginator
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor (private http: HttpClient) {
    // 1/ init
    this.matdatasource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
    this.http.get('http://example.org',{headers: this.headers})
      .subscribe(res => { 
        // 2/ populate with data
        this.matdatasource.data = res.data;
      });
  }
   
  // 3/ link paginator when empty dataSource is created
  // and paginator rendered
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I am trying this right now. Can You please tell me How I can pass the page options like current index, total records. etc on get request?

Comment: i think the total record will be inferred from the size of the data array in the dataSource. You don't have to provide it. For the currentIndex its a Input of the mat-paginator component  ( aka pageIndex) https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#MatPaginator so something like <mat-paginator [pageIndex]="myPageIndexFromComponent"></mat-paginator>

Comment: I have applied your fix. It's working very fine when I have enough number of records already fetch from the db. How to trigger a db function again/ or everytime when paginator's index changes? Lets say I have loaded first 20 elemetns then the paginator is working fine but the total record is 100 then how to load another 80 elements?

Comment: The server-side pagination with MatPaginator is another problem =) i recommend you to first read https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination combined with https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#advanced-data-sources. The solution will be to initialize your MatTableDataSource with an obervable that will emit the paginated page every time the pagination is changed

Comment: This is great suggestion to use advanced data source and it will definitely involve the observable.I got the concept and instead of  using it. I created one function called on_page_change() which is bound to page() property of pagination and it turns calls the new API.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your solution is correct way going ahead.  but to solve the The server-side pagination with MatPaginator, I have applied this workaround. What I have done is, I have just not binded the paginator with matdatasource in your solution.

Answer (score 4):

First, instantiate the paginator

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

Then populate the dataSource

```
this.matdatasource = new MatTableDataSource([])
```

And finally

```
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49110738/7882886) for proper Understanding

Answer (score 1):

You could try `@matheo/datasource` to build a clean setup of your database and datasource, and get everything in place without headaches.

I've mount different APIs with all kinds of pagination responses (and also no pagination data like Firebase), and I've handled the total count for all those cases with no issues.

Further details can be found at:
https://medium.com/@matheo/reactive-datasource-for-angular-1d869b0155f6

I could help you with your use case if you like the library
Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler version of @mateo-tibaquira's idea.  The highlights include:

- Combining `DataSource` with `Observable` to capture transient loading state and any errors resulting from the service call.
- Updating the paginator `length` based on the total count returned from the back end service call.
- A `Page<T>` generic class used to wrap the response array of type `T`, adding the pagination header info: `pageSize`, `pageIndex` and `totalCount`.
- Assumes back end calls support pagination parameters compatible with `<mat-table>` and `<mat-paginator>`.

This code is based on, and borrows heavily from, the excellent *Angular Material* blog entry [Angular Material Data Table: A Complete Example (Server Pagination, Filtering, Sorting)](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/).

**custom-data-source.ts**

```
import { map, catchError, finalize,
         debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, startWith, tap, delay 
       } from "rxjs/operators";

import { CollectionViewer, DataSource } from "@angular/cdk/collections";
import { MatPaginator }                 from '@angular/material';

import { Page } from '../model/page';

export class CustomDataSource<T> implements DataSource<T>, Observer<Page<T>> 
{
    private items = new BehaviorSubject<Page<T>>( new Page<T>() );
    private loading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    private err = new BehaviorSubject<any>( {} );

    protected paginator: MatPaginator;

    items$ = this.items.asObservable();
    loading$ = this.loading.asObservable();
    error$ = this.err.asObservable();

    closed = false;

    constructor( protected itemType: string ) {
    }

    next( results: Page<T> ) : void {
        console.debug( "Found items: ", this.itemType, results );
        if ( this.paginator ) {
            this.paginator.length = results.totalCount;
        }
        this.items.next( results );
    }
    error( errr: any ) : void {
        console.error( "Error loading items: ", this.itemType, errr );
        this.err.next( errr );
    }
    complete() : void {
        console.debug( "Done loading items.", this.itemType );
        this.loading.next( false );
    }

    connect( collectionViewer: CollectionViewer ) : Observable<Page<T>> {
        this.closed = false;
        return this.items$;
    }

    disconnect( collectionViewer: CollectionViewer ): void {
        this.closed = true;
        this.items.complete();
        this.loading.complete();
        this.err.complete();
    }

    protected preLoad() : void {
        this.err.next( {} );
        this.loading.next( true );
    }

    setPaginator( pgntr: MatPaginator ) : void {
        this.paginator = pgntr;
    }
}
```

**model/page.ts**

```
export class Page<T> extends Array<T> {
    public static readonly DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE: number = 10;

    pageIndex: number;
    pageSize: number;
    totalCount: number;

    constructor( pgIx?: number, pgSize?: number, tot?: number, items?: T[] )
    {
        super();
        this.pageIndex = pgIx ? pgIx : 0;
        this.pageSize = pgSize ? pgSize : 0;
        this.totalCount = tot ? tot : 0;
        if ( items && items.length > 0 ) {
            this.push( ...items );
        }
    }
}
```

**xyz-data-source.ts**

```
import { Xyz } from '../model/xyz';
import { CustomDataSource } from './custom-data-source';
import { XyzService } from '../service/xyz-service';

export class XyzDataSource extends CustomDataSource<Xyz>
{
    constructor( private xyzService: XyzService ) {
        super( 'Xyz' );
    }

    loadXyz( offset: number = 0, limit: number = 10, predicates?: any ) : void
    {
        this.preLoad();

        this.xyzService
            .searchXyz( offset, limit, predicates )
            .subscribe( this );
    }    
}
```